# Pick values from array in an order with every refresh

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to create a simple repetitive counter with PHP.
Let's say I have a array like this:

```
$letters = array("a","b","c");
```

I want to display this arrays in this normal order like:

- 1st refresh : a
- 2nd refresh : b
- 3rd refresh : c
- 4th refresh : a
- 5th refresh : b
- 6th refresh : c
- goes like this...

How can I a make it happen? Thanks.

Comment: what have you tried so far? What results did you get? Any error messages

Comment: For the same user or does user 1 see A, and user 2 see B the user 1 see C?

Comment: Save it in csv and make calls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using the $_SESSION variable, by holding the variable in a sessions and having a set of logic in place for each array index. For example:

```
   session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['refresh'])){
    $_SESSION['refresh'] = $letters[0];
}
else{

    switch ($_SESSION['refresh']) {
        case $letters[0]:
            $_SESSION['refresh'] = $letters[1];
            break;
        case $letters[1]:
            $_SESSION['refresh'] = $letters[2];
            break;
       case $letters[2]:
            $_SESSION['refresh'] = $letters[0];
            break;
    }

 }
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thanks.
What if I have hundreds of values in my array?

Answer (score 0):

This is only the logic to get that one.

First, you must make the url looks like this

http://yoursite/letter?now[]=0

and your code will looks like this

```
<?php

// http://yoursite/letter?now[]=0

$now = $_GET['now'];

$urlNow = null;
for ($i=0; $i < count($now); $i++) { 
    if($i !== 0){
        $urlNow += '&now[]=' . $now;        
    } else {
        $urlNow = 'now[]=' . $now
    }
}

//You can get your url now
```

i hope you'r understand with my logic.

Answer (score 0):

1. Start a session

   ```
   session_start();
   ```
2. Set a counter variable if it isn't set

   ```
   $_SESSION['counter'] = $_SESSION['counter'] ?? 0;
   ```
3. Define the array you'll iterate

   ```
   $letters = ["a","b","c"];
   ```
4. Output and increment the counter (3 is the length of the letters array)

   ```
   echo $letters[$_SESSION['counter']++ % 3];
   ```